# Alert on operation completion in windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

Using windows cmd I have to put large programs on compilation which take large amount of time. Everytime to know whether operation is complete or not I have to check cmd again and again. I want to know whether there is way by which I can make changes to cmd such that it gives me a signal that operation has been completed by playing sound or by opening a dialog etc.

Please share if anyone has some idea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There can be many ways to achieve this

This is the easiest

- While your code is compiling (ie compiling has just began) in the same cmd prompt

  type " **ctrl + G** " and press enter this will go to the input stream of cmd and will wait there until it can be executed , ctrl +G is the **BEL** character which gives you a single beep when you execute it .
  You can also enter multiple BEL characters to get multiple beeps upon completion of the task.
- A harder way could be ,  to write a python script that executes the compilation command say "g++ my_prog.cpp" and upon completion plays a sound or give you a simple popup notification via a windows message box.

Answer (score 4):

Include in yout batch file

```
msg console /time:3600 "The task has ended"
```

Send a message to the console and keep it open (if not closed by the user) 3600 seconds (if not indicated there is a 60 seconds timeout).

Comment: 'msg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @NathanKulzer, Maybe you are running a 32bit `cmd.exe` in a 64bit windows version. As `msg.exe` does not have a 32bit version inside `\windows\sysWOW64` it can not be found. If this is the case then try using the full path to the executable: `"%windir%\sysnative\msg.exe"`. `sysnative` is required as references to `system32` are redirected to `sysWOW64` when running 32bit code in a 64bit environment. Or you can ensure you are starting the 64bit version of `cmd.exe`

Comment: I assumed that there was only one version of cmd.exe, and it was the OS version. I'll try that!